# How to append multiple responses to useState in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-state

hope you can help me out a bit with this one! I'm sending multiple HTTP requests to get a list of movies. Currently, I'm using temp variable favMovies and pushing all results to it, and on the next .then() setting the state. This works fine, but I put a TODO comment and I feel there's a better way how to populate the state without additional .then(). Currently, if I uncomment my TODO, I only get 1 film added to my state... I'm obviously missing something.. Anyone can help?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

interface Movie {
  Title: string;
}

function App() {
  const [favouriteMovies, setFavouriteMovies] = useState<Movie[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=<API_KEY>&i=';
    const ids = ['t1', 't2', 't3'];
    const promises = [];
    const favMovies: Movie[] = [];
    const requests = ids.map((id) => `${url}${id}`);

    for (let i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
      promises.push(axios.get(requests[i]));
    }

    axios
      .all(promises)
      .then(
        axios.spread((...args) => {
          for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            favMovies[i] = args[i].data;
            // TODO: investigate why it's not appending all movies, but the last/first one
            // setFavouriteMovies([...favouriteMovies, args[i].data]);
          }
        })
      )
      .then(() => {
        setFavouriteMovies(favMovies);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {favouriteMovies.length
        ? favouriteMovies.map((m: any) => (
            <div key={Math.random()}>{m.Title}</div>
          ))
        : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

State changes are queued. Define the change based on the previous state, not the state the you can directly reference in the component scope.

```
setFavouriteMovies((previousMovies) => [...previousMovies, args[i].data]);
```